# TFS failed to start services

Tags: tfs

I am installing TFS 2013 on Windows 2008 Server and the Application Tier wizard throws an error - "Unable to increase the time allowed for Windows services to start to 600 seconds". It has a link on how to increase the Services timeout manually. When I checked the registry, it already has the ServicesPipeTimeout key (of type QWORD). I updated its value to 600000 and restarted the server. Still the wizard throws the same error. Is this related to the registry key being QWORD or DWORD or something else?

Comment: Are you running the installation as an administrator?

Comment: @DanielMann Yes.

Answer (score 0):

It should be **DWORD** type, you can try to delete the key and add it again with the DWORD type, then set the value to 600000, then restart and check this issue again. Also, please check if there are any errors in Event Viewer.

Please reference this article:
[The Windows Trace Session Manager service does not start and Event ID 7000 occurs.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/839803/the-windows-trace-session-manager-service-does-not-start-and-event-id-7000-occurs)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will it affect the server in anyway if I delete the existing key and create a new one with DWORD type?

Comment: @Vj87 The value change will apply to all the services on the machine, just affect the response time, you can backup it first if you worry about that,I checked the key on several machine, they are all DWORD type.

Comment: @Vj87 Have you resolved the issue by changing the DWORD type key?